# Simple Null Hypothesis Question

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study

Say you are regressing three explanatory variables with one dependent variable and only one of the variables has a p-value that is larger than the confidence interval, but the other two have a p-value less then the confidence interval. How does rejecting the null hypothesis work when this happens?

In my case:

V1: p-value = 0
V2: p-value = 0.005
V2: p-value = 0.910

For a 95% confidence interval.

H$_0$: The dependent variable is statistically independent from the explanatory variables

H$_A$: There is a correlation between the dependent variable and the explanatory variables

Comment: What do you mean by, "a p-value that is larger than the confidence interval"? That's not the way this works.

Comment: I added my null hypothesis, I hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Correlation is defined between exactly two variables. Either you mean a correlation with _each_ of the explanatory variables, or you mean something else by "correlation." As stated, that's a very unusual pair of hypotheses, and you wouldn't be able to test them with standard techniques. What is the practical problem you're trying to solve? Maybe we can help you say what you're trying to say.

Comment: I am trying to see if there is a relationship between the number of arrests in a particular region in 1986 and legal income, quarters employed, and duration of unemployment. It is an introductory statistics project and supposed to be quite simple. Thanks! @ssdecontrol

Comment: @Anonymous hypothesis testing is not simple stuff. Anyone who says otherwise is doing a poor job teaching. Have you heard of something called an "F test" yet? Trying to gauge what kind of answer your instructor might be looking for.

Comment: We did not cover F-tests. I was assigned this project in a laboratory setting of my statistics class. We have barely touched on regression this year and the project was to find an "interesting" topic, create an abstract of the topic, and report findings. My instructor is a condescending grad student which has made learning very difficult on the topic. My aim was to use some evidence to see if the explanatory variables contribute to my dependent variable in some way. @ssdecontrol

Comment: @Anonymous shame about your instructor! Stats is a great subject but it's easy to have a bad experience at first. I'm not going to update my answer since it won't really address the original question. You might want to ask a separate question with the `self-study` tag and explaining the context the way you explained it here. Something like "What evidence can I use to see if the explanatory variables contribute to my dependent variable in a multiple regression model?" should be fine for this site as long as you are careful to mention that you're a novice and don't know what to even search for.

Comment: To get you started, you can use something called a "[global F test](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~alicia/stat328/Multiple%20regression%20-%20F%20test.pdf)" that tests $H_0: \beta_1 = \beta-2 = \beta_3 = 0$. Most statistical software will report it somewhere.

Comment: You can also test different combinations of restrictions with the similar "nested F test."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *specify* a null hypothesis before you can try to reject one. "The" null hypothesis isn't some special universal thing.

You're asking about the linear model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3$. The p-value reported by your statistics software for the $j$th regression coefficient usually corresponds to the test

$$\begin{align}
H_\mathrm{null}&: \beta_j = 0\\
H_\mathrm{alternative}&: \beta_j \neq 0
\end{align}$$

which is a statement *only* about $\beta_j$ and says nothing about the other coefficients. The p-value associated with this test only ever says anything about this one test.

So your p-value for $V_1$ of $0.005$ only says that you can reject the null hypothesis that $V_1 = 0$ and only have an estimated 1-in-200 chance of being mistaken, based on the underlying data. This conclusion has no affect on, and is unaffected by, the other p-values.

Comment: I added my null hypothesis to the question. I believe your response answers my concern on the question.